# Saving Changes from an Unwind. Working in conjunction with <Back

Tags: swift, navigation

I have a problem understanding what I can do with the default Back BarButtonItem and how I can instigate a rewind.

The following shows a simplified layout.  I embed a ViewController in a Navigation controller and add a BarButtonItem ("Show") and connect to a second VC.  This adds the "Back" button to the second controller as shown below.
[image: Basic Back Button]

In the first VC I will show the user some details, in the second VC greater details will be shown.  With the show button and the default back button the user can easily navigate back and forth with expected behavior.

My problem comes in that the user will be allowed to modify the "More Details Here" and I will need to pass that to the first VC after the user unwinds back.

I cannot control-drag from the Back to the Exit icon but I have determined I can do this with a "Save" button on the navigation bar as shown.  (First dragging an Navigation Item to the top, then the BarButtonItem) then control-drag to Exit icon.

[image: With Save Button]

With the Save button, I can initiate a segue unwind and capture the changes back in my first VC with code like the following.

```
   @IBAction func unwindFromSecondVC(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {       
        if sender.source is AddCharacterViewController {
            if let senderVC = sender.source as? SecondViewController {
              details = senderVC.newDetails
            }       
        }
    }
```

This creates a problem when the user makes a change and then clicks the back button thereby loosing the changes.

My preferred solution would be to have the back button initiate a segue and transfer the changes.  But this does not appear to be possible.  My second solution would be to have the back button notice a transfer has not been made and stop the unwind seque.  Neither approach appears possible based on my research.

How should I best handle this problem while giving the user the common Back navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save any changes the user has made in the second VC, you could create a `SecondVCDelegate`:

```
protocol SecondVCDelegate : class {
    func detailsDidChange(newDetails: String)
}
```

In `SecondVC`, declare a `delegate` property:

```
weak var delegate: SecondVCDelegate?
```

And whenever the details change (the text field's value changed, or whatever event happened), you call

```
delegate?.detailsDidChange(newDetails: newDetails)
```

In `FirstVC.prepareForSegue`, you should set `self` as the delegate of `SecondVC`:

```
if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondVC {
    vc.delegate = self
}

// ...

extension FirstVC : SecondVCDelegate {
    func detailsDidChange(newDetails: String) {
        details = newDetails
    }
}
```

This way, whenever the `newDetails` change, `FirstVC` will be notified.

If you just want to notify `FirstVC` when the user leaves `SecondVC`, you could instead call the delegate in `SecondVC.viewWillDisappear` or a method like that.